# Quick simplification strategy for $\binom{3}{2}p^2(1-p) \le \sum_{k=3}^{5}\binom{5}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation

What is a quick simplification strategy to solve the following expression for $p$ by hand? 
(or less preferably, by a TI83/86 calculator). 
$$\binom{3}{2}p^2(1-p) \le \sum_{k=3}^{5}\binom{5}{k}p^k(1-p)^{5-k}$$

Something like this might show up on a probability exam.

Comment: Is $n$ arbitrary, $n=5$ or does $n$ have any other constrain?

Comment: Just $n =5$ as given in the problem I am working on.

Comment: Or if anyone would like to comment on how often they've seen expressions like this on undergraduate math exams and had to simplify them.